# Can't figure out which Cent OS to download

Tags: centos

There's some linux distros that I want to try, but none of the websites are as user friendly as Ubuntu =(

Which one should I download from this list?

http://mirror.rackspace.com/CentOS/6.3/isos/i386/

Comment: There is a [readme](http://mirror.rackspace.com/CentOS/6.3/isos/i386/0_README.txt) file in that directory explaining the purpose of each ISO image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link you provided, you've already chosen to download the 32 bit version (i386).  If you are concerned about bandwidth go with CentOS-6.3-i386-minimal.iso, otherwise download CentOS-6.3-i386-bin-DVD1.iso.  Considering you want to **try** CentOS, you don't need DVD2 as you can download the various packages as and when you need them using yum.

*Note that there is also a torrent for the DVDs; using that helps limit the resources used by the mirror sites*

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want. But as you said you want to test some distributions I would pick live DVD

If the torrent or not, depends on how you prefer to download it. The result will be the same.